# Laravel multiple form attributes need to be save in a database

Tags: php, database, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using this view. What I need is fill the database with complete name.

[image]
This is the view code segment.

```
<label>Name with Initials</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <select id="name_with_initials" name="name">
      <option selected="selected" value="mr">Mr.</option>
      <option value="mrs">Mrs.</option>
      <option value="miss">Miss.</option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="name_with_initials" class="form-control" placeholder="Name with Initials">
</div>
```

Here is the store function in controller.

```
$registerdetails = new registerdetails;
$title = Input::get('name');
$name  = Input::get('name_with_initials');
$name_with_initials = $title.' '.$name;
$registerdetails ->name_with_initials = $request ->name_with_initials;
```

My model attribute for that is `name_with_initials`

This works fine,but **save only the name not as mr mrs** why is that ?

Comment: Bro i don't want any reputation here i just want complete my project.if you know something u dont ask i guess.these type of questions can be silly for you but in my case it is not a silly one.thanks for the answer for a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have error in this line, here you are storing the complete name in `$name_with_initials` variable but at the time of storing still you are storing the data which came through request. change this line

```
$registerdetails ->name_with_initials = $request ->name_with_initials;
```

with

```
$registerdetails ->name_with_initials = $name_with_initials;
```